# Velocity operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, velocity, commutator

According to the Heisenberg equation of motion, the velocity operator is given by

$$\hat{v}=\frac{d \hat{r}}{dt} = \frac{1}{i\hbar}[\hat{r},\hat{H}].$$

**Question 1**: How can I find the velocity operator in a specific direction i.e. in the x-direction from this equation?

From Hamilton mechanics, we have
$$\hat{v_i}=\frac{d r_i}{d t} = \frac{\partial \hat{H}}{\partial p_i}.$$

**Question 2**: Is this velocity operator equivalent to the first velocity operator?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly That would appear to be an answer, not a comment, please consider making it one :)

Comment: This related post might be helpful: [Confused about definition of three dimensional position operator in QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556391)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't actually a well defined velocity operator in quantum mechanics (although it is possible to talk of phase velocity and group velocity). The easiest way to understand this is to reflect that a classical velocity necessitates a time trial over a measured distance, that is to say two measurements of position at different times. But the uncertainty principle means that the first measurement of position will create a superposition of momentum states, such that the notion of velocity is meaningless.

Comment: But it seems that if we define $\hat{v}=\frac{\overline{p}}{m}$ or in presence of electromagnetic field $\hat{v}=\frac{\overline{p}-q/A}{m}$ we can have a meaninful velocity operator that doesnt need to two separate measurement.

Answer (score 2):

To echo Charles Francis' answer, people don't normally discuss a velocity 'operator'. However what you can do is consider the classical vector:

$$ \vec{v} = \frac{d}{dt}\langle \vec{r} \rangle $$

which is given, as you say, by Heisenberg's equation of motion. To find this along the direction of a unit vector $\hat{n}$ you just compute $\vec{v}\cdot\hat{n}$. For the specific case of this being along a coordinate axis you would get eg:

$$ v_x = \frac{d}{dt}\langle x \rangle $$

As for the link to Hamilton's equation of motion, assuming $H$ is a sufficiently nice function of $p,x$ we can write (in 1D for simplicity):

$$[H(x,p),x] = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} [p,x] = -i\hbar \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$$

which links the two expressions.

Comment: nice answer. thank you. can you explain how you write $[H,x] = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p }[p,x]$. And, if we think the following sense, can we explain equality of above definitions of velocity? Let a Hamiltonian is written in k-space as $H=H(k_x,k_y)$, then (as $p_x = \hbar k_x$) $\hat{v}_x = \frac{\partial H}{\hbar\partial k_x}$. The velocity by Heisenberg equation is: as $\hat{x}=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial p_x}$, so, $\hat{v}_x = \frac{\partial H}{\hbar\partial k_x} - H\frac{\partial}{\hbar\partial k_x}$. Here, the last term in the last equation is extra. How to explain it?