# How to apply momentum operator on a wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, momentum

How do we apply the momentum operator on a wavefunction?

Wikipedia says

> the momentum operator can be written in the position basis as: ${ }^{[2]}$
> $$
> \hat{\mathbf{p}}\mapsto -i \hbar \nabla
> $$
> where $\nabla$ is the gradient operator, $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck constant, and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Does this mean that $$ -i \hbar \nabla \psi=-i \hbar\left(\hat{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi+\hat{\jmath} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \psi+\hat{k} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \psi\right)~?$$

I'm not sure this is correct because I found an expression in my book $\langle\mathbf{r}|\hat{\mathbf{p}}| \psi\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{i} \nabla\langle\mathbf{r} \mid \psi\rangle$. Since an operator acting on a ket gives a ket therefore the lhs is a bra ket of $\langle r$ and $\hat{p}|\psi\rangle$ hence a scalar but the rhs according to the Wikipedia definition will then be a vector.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: That is correct, that's how we do it in cartesian coordinates. You should be able to do it easily from here if you are familiar with the gradient operators.

Comment: If you are reading the Wikipedia article on the momentum operator than the answer to your question is in that article.  Did you not read the entire article?

Comment: @Mirae I found this expression in my book $\langle\mathbf{r}|\hat{\mathbf{p}}| \psi\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{i} \nabla\langle\mathbf{r} \mid \psi\rangle$

The lhs is a scalar because its a bra ket and the rhs then is a vector.

Comment: @Kashmiri the lhs is a Hilbert-space scalar, but a rotation-group ***vector***, (recalling the boldface momentum), and so is the rhs! Are you confused about *that*?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, yes I have done qm in one dimension now I started learning about it in 3d. I've learnt that an operator acting on a ket gives a ket, so according to that the lhs will be a bra ket of $\langle r$ and $\hat{p}|\psi\rangle$ 
hence a scalar.  However the rhs is a vector since it has a gradient operator in it.

Comment: As I said, there are *two types of vectors*: State and rotational ones!

Comment: [Possibly related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/556391/confused-about-definition-of-three-dimensional-position-operator-in-qm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am addressing the heart of your puzzlement, in my view. Your "?" expression is fine.

> I found this expression in my book ⟨|̂|⟩=-ℏ∇⟨∣⟩. The lhs is a scalar because its a bra | ket and the rhs then is a vector.

Vector in this context means two different things: A ket is a Hilbert space vector, possibly infinite dimensional, transforming under operators $\hat O$, while a dot product of it with a bra yields a Hilbert space scalar.

However, quite differently from that, a rotation vector is  a triplet transforming under the 3d rotation group, a 3×3 rotation matrix. A rotation scalar does not alter under such a rotation.

So, then, $\langle {\mathbf r}| \hat x |\psi\rangle = x \langle {\mathbf r}|\psi\rangle$ is a HS-scalar; and so is $\langle {\mathbf r}| \hat y |\psi\rangle = y \langle {\mathbf r}|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle {\mathbf r}| \hat z |\psi\rangle = z \langle {\mathbf r}|\psi\rangle$. The triplet of these three HS scalars constitutes a rotation vector,
$$\langle {\mathbf r}| \hat  {\mathbf r} |\psi\rangle =  {\mathbf r} \langle {\mathbf r}|\psi\rangle, $$
simply because these three HS scalars rotate into each other under a 3d space rotation, like the components of a classical vector. So both sides are HS scalars, and rotation vectors.

You may now repeat this with the three Cartesian components of the momentum operator, $\langle {\mathbf r}| \hat p_x |\psi\rangle = -i\hbar \partial_x  \langle {\mathbf r}|\psi\rangle$, etc, which, again stack to the 3-vectorial expression you saw in Townsend's book, ⟨|̂|⟩=-ℏ∇⟨∣⟩, again a triplet of HS scalars transforming like a vector under 3d rotations. The HS vectors that went into these scalars are infinite-dimensional here, which is evident from the fact the continuous gradients act on them.
$$
\langle {\mathbf r}| \hat {\mathbf p}|\psi\rangle \equiv  \langle {\mathbf r}|\begin{pmatrix} \hat p_x \\ \hat p_y \\ \hat p_z \end{pmatrix} |\psi\rangle= -i\hbar \begin{pmatrix}  \partial_x \\ \partial_y \\ \partial_z \end{pmatrix} \psi ({\mathbf r})\equiv -i\hbar \nabla  \psi ({\mathbf r}).
$$

---

NB The correct expression for the momentum operator in the coordinate representation is actually
$$
\hat {\mathbf p}= -i\hbar \int\!\! d^3 {\mathbf r} ~ |{\mathbf r}\rangle \nabla \langle {\mathbf r}|,
$$
a Hilbert space operator and rotational vector *since it’s boldface*. The meaningless expression in your comment does not correspond to Townsend’s correct expression!

Comment: Using the tensor product formalism in which    $\hat{P}|\psi\rangle=\left(\hat{P}_{x} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right)|\psi\rangle+\ldots$ I found $$\langle r|\hat{P}| \psi\rangle=\left(\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi+\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \psi+\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \psi\right).
$$ . This doesn't have any spatial unit vectors in it. 

But in *Townsends Quantum mechanics* he says that $$\langle\mathbf{r}|\hat{\mathbf{p}}| \psi\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{i} \nabla\langle\mathbf{r} \mid \psi\rangle$$ This has spatial unit vector

Comment: What you found is very wrong. You should never add the three components of the spacelike vector on the lhs. You should array them in a rotation vector Townsend specifies. It’s boldface. Do you understand what it means?

Comment: But $$\langle r|\hat{P}| \psi\rangle=\left(\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi+\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \psi+\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \psi\right)$$     follows from 
      $$\hat{P}|\psi\rangle=\left(\hat{P}_{x} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right)|\psi\rangle+\ldots$$

Comment: Your unbolded $\hat P$ is meaningless nonsense, as I explained. I explained you need a boldface rotational vector $\hat {\mathbf p}$, instead.  Stop using meaningless symbols. Townsend didn't, and I didn't, and you shouldn't.

Comment: Your unbolded ̂  is meaningless undefinable nonsense, as I explained. I explained you need a boldface rotational vector ̂ HS operator, instead. I updated my answer to address your quandary.

Comment: Thank you. I understand why we have  a  rotational vector expression but I still have a doubt. Please help me.

Comment: In the tensor product formalism we've $$\hat{\mathbf p}|\psi\rangle=\left(\hat{P}_{x} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right)|\psi\rangle+\ldots$$     If this step is correct then it follows that $$\langle {\mathbf r}|\hat{\mathbf p}| \psi\rangle=\left(\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi+\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \psi+\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \psi\right)$$ which you said is wrong. What went wrong in this derivation?

Comment: Your starting point is wrong: it is not a sum of three terms, but a vector with those as components; the one I wrote.

Comment: So can I write $$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\mathbf p} &=\hat{e}_{x}\left(\hat{p}_{x} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right) \\
&+\hat{e}_{y}\left(\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{p}_{y} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right) \\
&+\hat{e}_{z}\left(\mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{p}_{z}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Yes, basically. But be advised that the first carets signify a unit rotation vector, and the second a HS operator, as others have been warning you. I understand what you mean, but most readers cringe!

Comment: If   $$\begin{aligned} \hat{\mathbf p} &=\hat{e}_{x}\left(\hat{p}_{x} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right) \\ &+\hat{e}_{y}\left(\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{p}_{y} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right) \\ &+\hat{e}_{z}\left(\mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{p}_{z}\right) \end{aligned}$$ then what is 
     $$\hat{\mathbf p}^2|\psi\rangle
$$ ?

Comment: Well, the square of a boldface vector is a *scalar* operator rotation wise, so $\langle {\mathbf r}| \hat {\mathbf p}^2 |\psi\rangle = -\hbar^2 \nabla^2 \psi({\mathbf r})$. The position unit vectors go away.

Comment: So is it correct to write $\begin{aligned} \hat{\mathbf p} .\hat{\mathbf p}&=[\hat{e}_{x}\left(\hat{p}_{x} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right) \\ &+\hat{e}_{y}\left(\mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{p}_{y} \otimes \mathbb{1}\right) \\ &+\hat{e}_{z}\left(\mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{p}_{z}\right) ]^2\end{aligned}$ 

$=(\hat{p}_{x}^2 \otimes   1  \otimes  1)+(\hat{p}_{y}^2 \otimes  1 \otimes  1)+(\hat{p}_{z}^2\otimes 1\otimes   1)$

Comment: Yes it is. Rotationally, this is a scalar. HS-wise it is an operator.

Comment: Thank you so much professor. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. However your notation is not consistent. There is no reason for a 'hat' on top of $\bf p$ and $\hat P$ could als be replaced by $\bf p$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it appears as if the OP is using the carat to indicate an abstract operator.

Comment: @garyp He also uses it to indicate a unit vector. I also needed to use at least 30 characters.

Comment: I found this expression in my book $\langle\mathbf{r}|\hat{\mathbf{p}}| \psi\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{i} \nabla\langle\mathbf{r} \mid \psi\rangle$

The lhs is a scalar because its a bra ket and the rhs then is a vector.

Comment: The lhs looks like a "vector of scalars", so to speak.   I think we can all agree that the notation is not standard.  I'm curious:  what book?

Comment: @garyp, Townsend quantum mechanics